# asp.net mvc controller action and jquery ajax issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am trying to pass JsonResult into my jquery ajax, in my JS:

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/TestJson",       
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.length);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error'); 
        }

    });
```

in my Controller I have:

```
  public JsonResult TestJson ()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "VA" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "MD" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "DC" }
             };

       return this.Json(list);
    }
```

When I run it, the length is 3, but if I do something like alert (result[0]), I get [Object object]...so it looks like Json(list) doesn't jsonify it....

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used result[0].Value to get the value and result[0].Text to get the text property. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

you should try result[0].SelectListItem.Value/Text or other property

Comment: wait i check and revert, i have mistaken it is returning array of SelectListItem so result[0].Valiue/Text should work